# How can I create a "debug launch script" in Visual Studio for testing a class library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build-automation

I have 3 components that have to work together for developing a plugin:

- My Plugin (Class Library)
- Plugin Package Maker (Takes class library output and creates a plugin package for application)
- Application using the plugin

The manual workflow is as follows:

1. Build class library.
2. Run plugin package maker to produce a plugin package.
3. Copy plugin package to plugins folder.
4. Launch the host application.
5. Visual Studio "attach to process".

Is it possible to automate this workflow into a single F5 button push?

Comment: Would a pre/post build script not meet the requirements?

Comment: @Brendan If build script can launch a process and attach to it, then yes - but that is the question... also don't want it to launch automatically every time, just when I want to debug it.

Comment: How about inserting a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` into the debug builds of the plugin?